# Calculate sha1 hash of a stream but still use the stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

I have a function which will write/consume a stream like so.

```
consume(stream, function(e,d){});
```

But I would like to calculate the SHA1 hash of the stream right before calling this function. I know you can get the hash like so:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');

stream.on('data', function (data) {
    hash.update(data, 'utf8')
})

stream.on('end', function () {
    hash.digest('hex');c
})
```

But every time I try to call the consume function the stream is empty. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could pipe `stream` to both `sha1Calc` *and* `consume`:

```
stream.pipe(sha1Calc);
stream.pipe(consume);
```

Comment: But doesn't the first pipe consume/empty the stream? How does that work?

Comment: No, when you pipe to multiple streams, it writes to all of the streams.